# Getting error clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) while compile C++ file from terminal

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm getting this error

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

while i'm compiling simple cpp file from terminal

`gcc hello.cpp`

here's the content of hello.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// main() is where program execution begins.

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World"; // prints Hello World
   return 0;
}
```

I think it might conflict with XCode compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc hello.cpp` should be `g++ hello.cpp`

`gcc` is for compiling and linking C code, while `g++` is used for C++ code as you have it.

> I think it might conflict with XCode compiler?

No. The point is that the `gcc` command is also able to compile C++ code detected from the `.cpp` file extension, though the `libstdc++.a` won't be linked automatically.